# download a slack file using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack

I'm trying to download a file that was previously uploaded in slack.  I'm using the following link which says i need to use the url_private property of a message along with an authorization header.  https://api.slack.com/types/file#authentication

I've tried this and can't get it working.  Here is my current code.

```js
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "files.slack.com",
  "path": "/files-pri/FOO/download/foo.jpg",
  "rejectUnauthorized": "false",
  "headers": {
      "Authorization": "xoxp-foo-foo-foo"
  }
}

function pDownload(url, dest){
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var responseSent = false; // flag to make sure that response is sent only once.

    https.get(options, response => {
      response.pipe(file);
      file.on('finish', () =>{
        file.close(() => {
          if(responseSent)  return;
          responseSent = true;
          resolve();
        });
      });
    }).on('error', err => {
        if(responseSent)  return;
        responseSent = true;
        reject(err);
    });
  });
}

//example
pDownload(permalink, fileLocation)
  .then( ()=> console.log('downloaded file no issues...'))
  .catch( e => console.error('error while downloading', e));
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you post any outputs or errors you're getting, perhaps what your error handler receives?

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs at the link you shared the `Authorization` header is incorrect. You need to have `Bearer YOUR_SLACK_TOKEN` as the value like below.

`'Authorization': 'Bearer xoxp-foo-foo-foo-foo'`

https://api.slack.com/types/file#authentication